# Validation in Primefaces 4.0 blocks application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I am having an issue with prime faces 4.0. I implement a Java web application using spring and hibernate framework,prime faces 4.0 ,JSF.  I have a form which contains several tabs. I used require="true", for validation of text boxes. So if a mandatory field is left blank, the validation message is triggered.

Lets say I have a form which contains 4 tabs, and I have 6 fields which are mandatory. On filling the form, I forgot to fill 1 of the 6 mandatory fields and click on save. The validation message is displayed but it blocks the application. I cannot click on the tabs or even on my menu bar. It blocks the application completely.

Below is the error message in log:

Reference error : Primefaces is not defined

Please find the xhtml page below:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/WEB-INF/jsf/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form prependId="false">


    <p:panel header="#{toydetailsmsgs['toydetails.title']}" style="margin-top:10px">
            <p:messages />

    <h:panelGrid id="detail" columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="label,value">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
            <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true">

                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Home">

                    <h:panelGrid id="main" columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="label,value">
                        <h:outputText value="#{toydetailsmsgs['toydetails.id.title']}:*" />
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="toydetails_id" value="#{ToyDetailsComponent.toydetails.id}"style="width:200px;" required="true">   
                            <f:selectItems value="#{ToyDetailsComponent.toyLists}"
                            var="current" itemValue="#{current.toyCode}"
                            itemLabel="#{current.toyCode} - #{current.toyDesc}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="toyedetails_dob"
                        value="#{ToyDetailsComponent.toydetails.Dob}"
                        required="true" converter="primefacesCalendarConverter"/>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="tab2" title="Toy Details">
                    <h:panelGrid id="main1" columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="label,value">
                        <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="toydetails_date" value="#{ToyDetailsComponent.toydetails.Date}"
                        required="false" converter="primefacesCalendarConverter" >

                        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="toydetails_date"
                        update="toydetails_service" listener="#{ToyDetailsComponent.calculateService()}" />

                        </p:calendar>

                        <h:outputText value="#{toydetailsmsgs['toydetails.service.title']}:" />
                        <h:inputText id="toydetails_service" value="#{ToyDetailsComponent.toydetails.Service}"
                        required="false" label="toydetails_toyservice" disabled="true" style="width: 197px"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="tab3" title="Details">
                    <h:panelGrid id="detail5" columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="label,value">
                        <h:outputText value="#{toydetailsmsgs['toydetails.det.title']}:*" />
                        <h:inputText id="toydetails_det" value="#{ToyDetailsComponent.toydetails.Det}"
                        required="true"  style="width: 197px"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </p:tab>

                </p:tabView>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid id="button" columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="label,value">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton image="save" ajax="false"
                                style="margin-right:20px;"
                                value="#{toydetailsmsgs['navigation.save']}"
                                action="#{ToyDetailsComponent.save|ToyDetails(ToyDetailsComponent.toydetails)}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>

            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your webpage?

Comment: just add it in the post. Have a look thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have `h:head` tag in your page.

FAQ : http://primefaces.org/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

When you try to go to other tab it will try to submit the current tab. since your validation is failed jsf framework will throw a validator exception and directly renders response skipping the navigation. To avoid this add

```
 <p:tabView id="tabView" ....>
     <p:ajax event=”tabChange” process="@this" partialSubmit="true"   
               listener="if you wish to execute any action" />  
     <p:tab id="tab1" ../>
     <p:tab id="tab2" ../>  
 </p:tabView>
```

By this if you entered some fields and clicked on other tab they won't be processed and navigate to new tab. But when you come back you wont be able to see the last entered values in  the fields. If don't want this to happen save all the fields before going to other tabs.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Where do I need to place this in my code? after the <tabView> ? what do i need to insert in process?